# Auto Adjusting Width for each Tab of a Tabbed Panel

Tags: css, tabs, width, panels, spry

I have a tabbed panel with 6 tabs. I'd like to set the CSS so that the width of each tab changes to auto-fit the text in that tab, so tabs with long sentences are wider, & tabs with shorter sentences are slimmer. I'd also like the maximum width of the panel to be 900px.

This is my CSS so far:

```
#TabbedPanels2 .TabbedPanelsContentGroup {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:70%;
margin-top:105px;
max-width:900px;
}
```

The issue right now is that all 6 of the tabs always stay at 900px, instead of auto-adjusting down to fit the text. You can see the results here:
[www.shellshockeddoc.com](http://www.shellshockeddoc.com/) Specifically with the tabs for "Watch" & "Screenings"

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `width: 100%; max-width: 900px;` and also define `min-width: 0px;` as you are having problem for this.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it & it gave me the same results as before. The tabs always seem to stay at 900px no matter what.

Comment: Still no luck. The min-width didn't change anything.

Comment: you have not defined max-width in your site just check that

Comment: Thanks! I just made all the changes & uploaded the new CSS, but still the same results.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block;` will cause an element to span the width of its content rather than the width of its container. If you add `display: inline-block;` to both `.TabbedPanelsContent` and `.TabbedPanelsContentGroup` and then add `text-align: center;` to `.TabbedPanels` you'll get (centered) tab boxes of varying widths depending on the width of their content.

Answer (score 0):

remove width of tab class and add `margin:0 auto;padding:3px`